# Rewrite URL using htaccess in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

For a php project, using .htaccess I want to rewrite:

```
http://localhost/pms/pms.php?sect=add_project_detail&id=7
```

with:

```
http://localhost/pms/pms/add_project_detail/7
```

I use `RewriteRule ^pms/(.*)$ pms.php?sect=$1 [PT,L]`and it works fine for

```
http://localhost/pms/pms/add_project_detail
```

but what for `$id=7`

**Response back @ Anton:**

`RewriteRule ^pms/([A-Za-z_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ pms.php?sect=$1&id=$2` is fine for `http://localhost/pms/pms/add_project_detail/7` 
but it stop `http://localhost/pms/pms/add_project_detail` to work and if i use both  `RewriteRule ^pms/(.*)$ pms.php?sect=$1 [PT,L]` and 
`RewriteRule ^pms/([A-Za-z_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ pms.php?sect=$1&id=$2` no one works

```
http://localhost/pms/pms/add_project_detail
```

or

```
http://localhost/pms/pms/add_project_detail/7
```

thanks.

Comment: Try without the PT flags perhaps, what do they do?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^pms/pms/([A-Za-z_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ pms.php?sect=$1&id=$2
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^pms/([A-Za-z_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ pms.php?sect=$1&id=$2 is fine for http://localhost/pms/pms/add_project_detail/7 
but it  stop http://localhost/pms/pms/add_project_detail to work and if i use RewriteRule ^pms/(.*)$ pms.php?sect=$1 [PT,L] and 
RewriteRule ^pms/([A-Za-z_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ pms.php?sect=$1&id=$2 no one works 
http://localhost/pms/pms/add_project_detail
or
http://localhost/pms/pms/add_project_detail/7

Comment: You'll need to use two cases i suppose, the first one being the one i posted with [L] added to it. And the next one your initial one, test that and report back with results :)